# D3 Sticky Zoomable Treemaps

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to apply transitions to a zoomable treemap, as demonstrated in Mike Bostock's example here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/

Particularly, I want to tag the treemap as sticky, so that when I resort, at any level of the hierarchy of data, the cells stay in the same order.  However, the interface fails when I enable the sticky tag.  [Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rho1nboc/), line 404 is the line which creates the sticky values, and does not work when uncommented. Here's a look at the treemap:

```
var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })
.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; })
 // .sticky(function(d){return true;})
.ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
.round(false);
```

In the D3 API, I noticed the line below, but I'm not sure how to recall each treemap as sticky when parsing through the data.  Any ideas?

> Implementation note: sticky treemaps cache the array of nodes internally; therefore, it is not possible to reuse the same layout instance on multiple datasets. To reset the cached state when switching datasets with a sticky layout, call sticky(true) again. Since version 1.25.0, hierarchy layouts no longer copy the input data by default on each invocation, so it may be possible to eliminate caching and make the layout fully stateless.

Comment: `.sticky()` doesn't take a function. Use `.sticky(true)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but .sticky(true) still doesn't work.

Comment: So call `.sticky()` again when setting new data -- `treemap.sticky(true).nodes({_children: d._children});` http://jsfiddle.net/rho1nboc/1/